# Unexpected token else, but in "if" there's no semicolon

Tags: javascript, if-statement, token

I'm sure everything is right, but error exists. I don't know why... Here's a part of my code. Error points the string with "else", and this "else" were highlighted by me by double asterisk in both sides. This "highlighting" isn't exist in the real code. The real code isn't working by the error

```
  If(e==true && e1==true)
  {
    for (i=0; i<l1; i++)
    {
        if (lat.indexOf(st1.charAt(i)) == -1)
        {
            s5=s5+st1.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    for (i=0; i<l2; i++)
    {
        m=st2.charAt(i);
        n=i;
        for (j=i+1; j<l2; j++)
        {
            if (a.charAt(j) < m)
            {
                m=st2.charAt(j);
                n=j;
            }
            if (m != st2.charAt(i))
            {
                st2=st2.slice(0,i)+m+st2.slice(i+1,n)+st2.charAt(i)+st2.slice(n+1,l2);              
            }
        }
    }   
  } 
  **else**
  {
```

Comment: javascript is case sensitive.. use if NOT "If"..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the first line from `If(e==true && e1==true)` to `if (e==true && e1==true)`.

As an aside I'd suggest, for your own sake and sanity, naming your variables more descriptively; you'll kick yourself if you come back to your code in future and can't work out what you've tried to write.